# show content to first time visitor of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want a piece of content to display to first time visitors of a rails app, so I wrote a helper method that checks session and stores a cookie.

My controllers are set up like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :first_time_visiting?

  def first_time_visiting?
    if session[:first_time].nil?
        cookies.permanent[:first_time] = 1
    end
  end
end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :first_time_visiting?
end
```

And then I'm calling the method in my view like this:

```
<% if first_time_visiting? %>
  <div class="new-visitor-show">Test</div>
<% end %>
```

I should not be seeing "Test" after first visit, but I am. Am I using the helper method incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this (without helper):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :first_time_visit, unless: -> { cookies[:first_visit] }

  def first_time_visit
     cookies.permanent[:first_visit] = 1
     @first_visit = true
  end
end
```

The function `first_time_visit` will be called only once, and so in the view :

```
<% if @first_visit %>
  <div class="new-visitor-show">Test</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah, I had no idea. Thanks! Just so I understand: you're defining a before_action that sets a cookie and an instance variable called @first_visit unless that cookie already exists in user's browser?

Comment: If the cookie is already set, the method `first_time_visit` will not be called, and so @first_visit will be nil

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking the `cookies` instead `session`.

```
  def first_time_visiting?
    if cookies[:first_time].nil?
      cookies.permanent[:first_time] = true
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```